# Views of Node Revision with Revision Update Date Expose filter

Tags: views, nodes

I have a Views of Node Revision with **Revision Update Date** Exposed.

Exposed form rendered as "textfield" widget by default, I want to have Date popup calendar instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and Enable the module 'better_exposed_filters'
2. Refresh view, then change Exposed form style to use Better Exposed Filters (under advanced).
3. Under BEF settings, use 'jQuery UI Datepicker' widget.